# Download and execute a file hosted on a remote server?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote, vbscript

Is it possible to download and execute a file hosted on a remote server using a .vbs script? My below attempt doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""\\12.345.67.789\filename.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: You **say** you’re downloading the file, but, as far as I can see, you aren’t — you’re just trying to execute it from its remote location.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you what you want. Be sure to set the local file name (sLocalFile) to a path that your user has rights to write to or it will fail. Further, most antivirus apps will treat this as malware.

```
' variables
Dim xHttp, oStream, oShell, sRemoteURI, sLocalFile

' constants
Const klBinary = 1
Const klOverwrite = 2

' defined values
sRemoteURI = "https://example.com/filename.exe"
sLocalFile = """%appdata%\filename.exe"""

' create the web request
Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xHttp.Open "GET", sRemoteURI, False
xHttp.Send

' save the file locally
Set oStream = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
oStream.Type = klBinary
oStream.Open
oStream.Write xHttp.responseBody
oStream.SaveToFile sLocalFile, klOverwrite
Set oStream = Nothing
Set xHttp = Nothing

' run the file
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run(sLocalFile)
Set oShell = Nothing
```